# Refresh parent Content out of child View

Tags: angular, ionic2

is there a simple way, where I can tell the Parent View to refresh it's content?

[image: Filter Video]

In this case I'm changing the sort Model and would like to query my http Request with this new Model status.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoadingController,NavController,PopoverController,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
template: `
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="suchService.sort" class="popover-page">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Entfernung aufsteigend</ion-label>
    <ion-radio (click)="sortchange()"value=""></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Neueste zuerst</ion-label>
    <ion-radio (click)="sortchange()"value="9"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Preis aufsteigend</ion-label>
    <ion-radio (click)="sortchange()"value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
`
})
class PopoverPage {

constructor(private suchService: SuchService, private viewController: ViewController) {

}
sortchange(){
  console.log("HALLO?"); <-- CALL FUNCTION OF ERGEBNISSE
  this.viewController.dismiss();
}
}
export class Ergebnisse {
.....
getResults(){...}
....
}
```

I can't import the Ergebnisse class into my Popoverpage... Even if I use another .ts File for the Popoverpage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks everybody for your answer.

Put I used some ionic specific API to solve it.

I was creating the Child Popover via

```
presentPopover(ev) {

let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {});

popover.present({
  ev: ev
});
```

Then there is some listener from Ionic which solves my Problem.

```
popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
//Can Use Data which is passed by Popover
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a great read about component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Use @Output in your child and then listen for it in the parent

child component .ts - declare an Output variable that is going to emit an event when it is called in your function.

```
@Output() sortChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

sortChange() {
  this.sortChangedEvent.emit({sortOrder: 'asc'});
}
```

Parent component html - link the child event emitter with a function in your parent component

```
<child-component (sortChange)="refereshListOrder($event)"></child-component>
```

Parent component .ts - create a function which listens for the event

```
refreshListOrder(event) {
  // sudo code below
  service.getData().withSortOrder(event.sortOrder);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you fast Reply! But refreshListOrder is never called.
Does Ionic popover.create indeed create a Parent/Child Relationship as Angular understands?